# TableLayout header row expands underneath next views

Tags: android

I dont know what is happening below in below xmf flie recyclerview's item is similar as the table layout in xml. When i click recent tab of android system buttons and again when i open app which i left the screen previously.

```
    activity_point_table.xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_point_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:background="@color/md_blue_50"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_teamname"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_match"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="M" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_win"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="W" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_loss"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="L" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_tie"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="T" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_noresult"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="NR" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_pts"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="Pts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_nrr"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="NRR" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_point_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_point_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No Records in Point Table"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

### Before

[image: Before i click recent tab from android system navigation.]

### After

[image: After i click recent tab from android system navigation.]

Comment: Use VerticalLayout instead of TableLayout

Comment: @David LinearLayout?

Comment: If anything, GridLayout would be preferable

Comment: aha, yes. you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_point_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:background="@color/md_blue_50"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_teamname"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_match"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="M" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_win"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="W" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_loss"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="L" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_tie"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="T" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_noresult"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="NR" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_pts"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="Pts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_nrr"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="NRR" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_point_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_point_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No Records in Point Table"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ll_point_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:background="@color/md_blue_50"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_teamname"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_match"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="M" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_win"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="W" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_loss"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="L" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_tie"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="T" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_noresult"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="NR" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_pts"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="Pts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_head_pt_nrr"
                style="@style/PTTableHeaderTextView"
                android:text="NRR" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_point_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_point_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No Records in Point Table"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```